# How to flip a chessboard while preserving the move stack in python chess?

Tags: python, chess

I'm implementing a chess engine using NegaScout in Python using Python Chess. I've found a handy function `chess.Board.apply_mirror()` which reverses the board so black is white and vice versa. This is essential for Negamax and NegaScout. However, this deletes the move stack. I can manually reverse all of the moves in the move stack, copy it to a list, reverse each one and assign it back to the flipped board, but is there an easier way to do this? I need the full history of the position since the base of the tree (the text move) to rewind moves for my tree search.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to flip the board with NegaMax, but just to invert evaluation. Check [my Negamax implementation](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Hv_s1uEpIBq40wMkZ4fNAlSMmlgQ_lWg?usp=sharing) in [my Lichess BOT](https://lichess.org/@/Ramses-Chess).